# Changing Binding of ObservableObject in a subview re-renders all subviews of dependent on the object

Tags: swiftui

I have an `@ObservedObject var filter: Filter` property in my `FilterPageView`, when I pass a property of this object to a subview which contains a list and mutates the passed property, changes in the property re-initialises all subviews in `FilterPageView` so the animation that is supposed to happen in the subview doesn't work.

FWIW, It works fine when I pass a `@State var selectedItems: Set<String>` as a binding instead of `filter. selectedCities`

```
class Filter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedCities: Set<String> = []
    @Published var selectedUniversities: Set<University> = []
```

```
struct FilterPageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var filter: Filter

    var body: some View {
        // --> When SelectableListView changes the passed property, this line
        //     is being executed and it creates all subviews from scratch.
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    SelectableListView(selectedItems: $filter.selectedCities)
                } label: {
                    Text("Cities")
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SelectableListView(
                        selectedItems: $filter.selectedUniversities)
                } label: {
                    Text("Universities")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SelectableListView<T: Hashable>: View {
    @Binding var selectedItems: Set<T>
    
   // List showing and changing selectedItems with .remove and .insert
}
```

Comment: This should be done with view model and environment object, that shouldn't cause the problem.

Comment: Views are just values there is nothing wrong with them being re-init, it's basically negligible performance wise. Something else must be the reason of the animation glitch. Please show your `List` or `ForEach` because those are a common place for mistakes in View identity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how `ObservableObject`s & `View`s work. From the docs of `@ObservedObject`

> A property wrapper type that subscribes to an observable object and invalidates a view whenever the observable object changes

So a View that has observes an `ObservableObject` via `@ObservedObject` will be redrawn whenever there is a change to the observed object.

It works with a `@State` because a State change doesn't invalidate the entire view, but only the child views that depend on it.

Comment: Thanks that is really useful! In which case would you say if there is a problem with my design, because in my case animations don't work in the subview, I can workaround that by using an extra state variable and changing my the set in the ObservedObject  only when the view is dismissed but it is a hacky solution and I am curious about proper way of doing this.

Comment: Since View structs are just data it's better to say recomputed rather than "redrawn"